# I can't install opencv-python because I don't have vs?

Tags: python, opencv

whenever I try to pip install opencv-python it comes with an error saying I need to install visual studio 2022 but I already have it installed. I'm completely out of ideas for how to fix this and really need opencv right now to work on my device.

I've tried to use opencv-contrib-python as well but that's giving me the same error.
the error message is:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' 'c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\NOAH~1.ROB\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb6spxf7z'
       cwd: C:\Users\noah.robb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g3bef9kp\opencv-contrib-python
  Complete output (332 lines):
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      Ninja

    does not support platform specification, but platform

      x64

    was specified.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/noah.robb/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-g3bef9kp/opencv-contrib-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      Visual Studio 17 2022

    could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/noah.robb/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-g3bef9kp/opencv-contrib-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      Ninja

    does not support platform specification, but platform

      x64

    was specified.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/noah.robb/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-g3bef9kp/opencv-contrib-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      Visual Studio 16 2019

    could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/noah.robb/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-g3bef9kp/opencv-contrib-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      Ninja

    does not support platform specification, but platform

      x64

    was specified.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/noah.robb/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-g3bef9kp/opencv-contrib-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      Visual Studio 15 2017

    could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/noah.robb/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-g3bef9kp/opencv-contrib-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      NMake Makefiles

    does not support platform specification, but platform

      x64

    was specified.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/noah.robb/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-g3bef9kp/opencv-contrib-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      NMake Makefiles

    does not support platform specification, but platform

      x64

    was specified.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/noah.robb/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-g3bef9kp/opencv-contrib-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      NMake Makefiles

    does not support platform specification, but platform

      x64

    was specified.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/noah.robb/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-g3bef9kp/opencv-contrib-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".


  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  ********************************************************************************
  scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.

  Building windows wheels for Python 3.8 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2022.
  Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":

    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

  Or with "Visual Studio 2019":

    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

  Or with "Visual Studio 2022":

    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

  ********************************************************************************
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-contrib-python
  Running setup.py clean for opencv-contrib-python
Failed to build opencv-contrib-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-contrib-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: what *precisely* did you do? there is a python 3.8 windows package of `opencv-python` and that should install without issues. your error log is cut a bit short. show *everything*. your system seems broken. when in doubt, clean up the system, remove all python, start fresh.

Comment: this is really the only thing that i left out:

Comment: Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/61/ee4496192ed27f657532fdf0d814b05b9787e7fc5122ed3ca57282bae69c/opencv-python-4.5.5.64.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3; python_version >= "3.8" in c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.22.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python
  Building wheel for opencv-python (PEP 517) ... error

Comment: there should be no building of wheels involved. opencv-python packages are binary. when I install opencv-contrib-python on my python 3.10, pip downloads opencv_contrib_python-4.5.5.64-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl and there is no building involved at all. the same should happen for python 3.8. why don't you share the exact command line you use to install?

Comment: pip install opencv-contrib-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran this command, and it solved the problem for me:
`pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`
then ran this with a version specified:
`pip install -U opencv-python==4.5.5.62`

Answer (score 1):

You have to install v143 c++ build tools with VS installer under "universal windows platform development" section.